# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jsonpath"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, rubygems, bundler

I have 2 gems `k8s-client` and `kubeclient` , which require different versions of `jsonpath`.
But bundler is failing to resolve/install gems due to this difference. Even if I add an additional gem installation of jsonpath itself , it's failing with same.

```
In Gemfile:
    k8s-client was resolved to 0.10.3, which depends on
      jsonpath (~> 0.9.5)

    kubeclient (= 4.9.3) was resolved to 4.9.3, which depends on
      jsonpath (~> 1.0)
```

I tried adding gem `'jsonpath','1.1.2'` in the Gemfile which should Ideally satisfy both but it still gives same error . Anyone knows why ? How to resolve this ?

- Updating `k8s-client` to 0.10.4 as well , get the same error , as it remains dependent on jsonpath (~>0.9.5) ref - https://rubygems.org/gems/k8s-client/versions/0.10.4

PS - There is no Gemfile.lock created yet , so no suggestions to delete that file please. This `bundle install` will run as part of docker image build , so I wouldn't prefer doing `bundle update` as well, as suggested by other Stackoverflow answers.

Thank you.

Gemfile ->

```
group :external do
  gem 'jsonpath','1.1.2'
  gem 'fluent-plugin-route'
  gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd'
  gem 'fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter'
end

group :core do
  gem 'fluentd'
  gem 'kubeclient','4.9.3'
  gem 'k8s-client'
  gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus'
  gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier'
  gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.1.2` will not satisfy `~> 0.9.5` and `~> 1.0`

`~> 0.9.5` contains the range `>= 0.9.5` and `< 1.0`

`~> 1.0` contains the range `>= 1.0` and `< 2.0`

[Reference](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/rubys-pessimistic-operator)

Comment: That means this cannot be resolved :O  ?
as the available versions are -> 

`jsonpath-0.9.9.gem`                                      
`jsonpath-1.0.5.gem`

Comment: Yes, seems like you're gonna have to downgrade `kubeclient` a fair bit.

Comment: Solution I'm using is , forking the k8s-client and upgrading jsonpath gemspec dependency and using that gem. Since kubeclient <=4.9.2 has a security vulnerabiliity , so yea..